# How to modify thickness of KDE taskbar in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, themes, kde, oxygen

I've been using the Oxygen theme in both Kubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. The boxes on the taskbar look fine in 14.04:

[image: KDE Oxygen Taskbar Desktop 14.04]

In 16.04 however, the boxes are thinner relative to the other icons, meaning some of the text can get chopped off, and it just looks wrong. It's only a few pixels, but enough. Example:

[image: KDE Oxygen Taskbar Desktop 16.04]

On my laptop running 16.04, it's even worse, with the text being unreadable:

[image: KDE Oxygen Taskbar Laptop 16.04]

I believe the taskbar section of the theme is defined in `tasks.svgz` (by default in `/usr/share/kde4/apps/desktoptheme/oxygen`). Problem is, I'm not sure what to modify to increase the vertical size of the boxes.

Is it a graphical editor job (using Inkscape or similar), or can it be adjusted with a text editor? If the latter, which lines in that file would need changing?